# Memoria a eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Me gustaria que mi eclipse vaya fluido, 
Tengo un i7 de 4º generacion, 8gb ram DDR3, SSD 256 gb, he configurado esto en mi eclipse.ini:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-Xverify:none
```

¿Creeis que esta bien o puedo subirle un poco mas?, si tuviese 16gb ram cual de todos los atributos tengo que subirle?

Comment: Le has definido un máximo de 20 GB de memoria, creo te sobra un 0 en Xmx20480. En cualquier caso con eso debería ir ya todo lo fluido que eclipse puede ir

Comment: gracias por el comentario, editado lo del 0 de más, y si quisera que vaya más fluido aún q deberia aumentar?

Comment: Lo que te limita ya es la velocidad de proceso pura: ¿una CPU más rápida? ¿RAM más rápida?. Procura cerrar los proyectos del "workspace" que no necesites para evitar que eclipse se entretenga con ellos y malgaste memoria

Comment: @sirdaiz me parece muy raro que con esas caracteristicas de tu pc y la configuración que muestras, tengas problemas para usar eclipse, ¿no va "fluido", reiniciaste la pc?

Answer (score 1):

Usando eclipse, lo que debes incrementar es el "heap size" que en realidad lo tienes definido en 2MB, esta es la propiedad que debes modificar.

```
-Xmx2048m
```

Que es el máximo permitido que definiste:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

Pero me llama la atención las características de tu PC en realidad lo anterior es suficiente para que Eclipse funcione correctamente. Es importante no tener muchos proyectos en tu workspace porque eso puede provocar lentitud al cargar los proyectos al inicio.

Revisar:
[**Como incrementar el Heap size disponible para eclipse.**](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F)